# MongoDB: Is it ok to run multiple mongod on the same directory(dbpath)?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm currently working with Docker, I use `mongo` image for my DB container. For persistent storage, I mounted host machine's directory(e.g. `/var/docker/data/db`) to container(e.g. `/data/db`).

By now, whenever I wanted to run mongo shell and connect to my db I was doing these things:

- Attach to running MongoDB container using `docker exec -it <container> bash`
- Run `mongo` shell inside the container
- Do some job

But I think it'll be much better if I could run `mongod` separately on the host machine, not in the container, and then connect to it even when the container is not running.

So is it possible to doing so? If I run two `mongod` process on the same directory(files), will there be an file access conflict?

If someone did similar kind of work, share me your experience please. Thanks.

Comment: Let me understand this correctly. You want to run two `mongod` processes using the same `dbpath` at the same time, using the same `dbpath`? If a `mongod` process is running using that directory, subsequent `mongod` processes will not be able to run using the same path, since this is very unsafe and thus `mongod` will prevent you from doing it.

Comment: Yes you've understood it correctly. Ok so the answer is IMPOSSIBLE thanks

Comment: Instead of bind-mounting a directory from the host, you could use a separate `volume` for each mongodb container

Comment: I can do that, but what I was looking for was a way to use the same volume for the host and the container.